# Why i cannot fetch subclass from base class repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, inheritance, spring-data

I have an inheritance in my data model. I have :

```
public class User(){

private String login;

private String password;

// accessors

}
```

I have also three class which extends User class :

```
public class Candidate() extends User{

 // specific attributes and accessors

}

public class Recruiter() extends User{

 // specific attributes and accessors

}

public class Administrator() extends User{

 // specific attributes and accessors

}
```

I use Spring data JPA to fetch data from database. Here is the code of UserRepository :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findOneByActivationKey(String activationKey);

    List<User> findAllByActivatedIsFalseAndCreatedDateBefore(DateTime dateTime);

    Optional<User> findOneByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findOneByLogin(String login);

    void delete(User t);

}
```

The problem arrived when i one of my controller, i fetch data from database and i check if the instanceof User fetch is Candidate :

```
 String currentEmail = SecurityUtils.getCurrentEmail();
        Optional<User> currentUser = userRepository.findOneByEmail(currentEmail);
        if(currentUser.isPresent() && currentUser.get() instanceof Candidate){ 

            ((Candidate)currentUser.get() ).addLink(link);
        }
```

In this code, currentUser.get() always return User and neither Candidate, Recruiter or Administrator.
I don't want to send another database request to fetch information using candidateRepository or recruiterRepository. 
Where am i wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Your repository is for type User. That's why you get instances of User.